What are the benefits to attaching a router to our T-Mobile gateway?
We are evaluating a T-Mobile gateway device, which according to my son, "is a glorified hotspot".
Our previous internet is a Cox provided modem/router.
My Epson WorkForce Pro printer wants to talk with a router and doesn't recognize our T-Mobile network.
My son suggests getting a router to attach to the T-Mobile gateway, so he can access our network from outside our household and hopefully it will enable the printer. (We can save over $80USD by switching from Cox to T-Mobile.)
Questions:

What are the benefits to attaching a router to our T-Mobile gateway?
Will attaching a router to the T-Mobile gateway resolve our issues (of having MAC addresses)?

Update 1:

Printer is Epson WorkForce Pro, WF-4820.
The T-Mobile thing is also known as a mobile hotspot.
The MAC address conclusion is from the printer and from my son trying to access the network outside of the house. With the Cox modem/router he can access devices on the network by using MAC addresses.


What model is your T-Mobile gateway and your Workforce Pro printer?   Other then your printer, can you have multiple devices, and what devices are using wifi and what devices are using Ethernet?    The benefits of attaching a router to your T-Mobile gateway is it will give you/your son more control of the network.  If the issue you are having is really one of reaching MAC addresses of devices on the same LAN, then a router can help, but it could also be a matter of configuring your t-mobile gateway.   (Does it have WIFI isolation turned on?)

I wonder what your son meant by that, given that hotspots are glorified wireless routers. From what I found about the T-Mobile Gateway, it doesn't look any better or worse than a typical ISP provided router/modem/gateway, and it doesn't look like it serves Wi-Fi in a particularly weird way, either. (There's no fundamental difference between how a router does it and how a hotspot does it.) So I'm not sure if question 1 can be answered satisfactorily given that it's about two devices of the same kind.

As for question two.... where did "(of having MAC addresses)" come from? How did you conclude that this is an issue?

If your new ISP is using CG-NAT that would explain why it isn't accessible from outside, but no, it has nothing to do with the device and adding a router wouldn't change anything that's done at the service level, several step before it reaches your house. PS - T-Mobile does use CG-NAT. You got what you payed for.
